# STANDARD_PRICE_NOT_DEFINED for more than 1 currency

Tags: test-setup, pricebookentry

I tried to populate PriceBookEntry for different currency in test class.It works for only one for one currency, when i try to add different currency it fail.

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 1; first
>   error: STANDARD_PRICE_NOT_DEFINED, No standard price defined for this
>   product: []

Here is the code:

```
 //insert test product
   Product2 prod=new Product2(Name='SalesPrice',Family='SalesPrice');

   insert prod;


   // Get standard price book ID.
   // This is available irrespective of the state of SeeAllData.
   Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

   system.debug('pricebookId = ' + pricebookId );

   //insert pricebookentry
   PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = pricebookId, Product2Id = prod.Id,
            UnitPrice = 10000, IsActive = true);
    insert standardPrice;

   // Create a custom price book
    Pricebook2 customPB = new Pricebook2(Name='Standard Price Book', isActive=true);
    insert customPB;


    List<PricebookEntry> listPBE = new List<PricebookEntry>();
    PricebookEntry customPrice1 = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = customPB.Id, Product2Id = prod.Id,CurrencyIsoCode ='GBP',
    UnitPrice = 0.0, IsActive = true);
    listPBE.add(customPrice1);

    PricebookEntry customPrice2 = new PricebookEntry(
    Pricebook2Id = customPB.Id, Product2Id = prod.Id,CurrencyIsoCode ='USD',
    UnitPrice = 0.0, IsActive = true);
    listPBE.add(customPrice2);

   insert listPBE;
```

CustomPrice1 is successfully inserted but customPrice2 is fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution whereby I need to define the currency one by one.

Example:

```
 List<Product2> listProd = new List<Product2>();
       Product2 prod=new Product2(Name='Radio',Family='Walkman',CurrencyIsoCode ='GBP');
       listProd.add(prod);

       Product2 prod1=new Product2(Name='Radio',Family='Walkman',CurrencyIsoCode ='USD');
       listProd.add(prod1);

       Product2 prod2=new Product2(Name='Radio',Family='Walkman',CurrencyIsoCode ='EUR');
       listProd.add(prod2);

       Product2 prod3=new Product2(Name='Radio',Family='Walkman',CurrencyIsoCode ='AUD');
       listProd.add(prod3);

       insert listProd;

       // Get standard price book ID.
       // This is available irrespective of the state of SeeAllData.
       Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

        //insert pricebookentry for eacy currency
       List<PriceBookEntry> listStdPrice = new List<PriceBookEntry>();

        PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(
                Pricebook2Id = pricebookId, Product2Id = prod.Id,
                UnitPrice = 0.0, IsActive = true);
        listStdPrice.add(standardPrice);

        PricebookEntry standardPrice1 = new PricebookEntry(
                Pricebook2Id = pricebookId, Product2Id = prod.Id,
                UnitPrice = 0.0, IsActive = true,CurrencyIsoCode ='USD');
        listStdPrice.add(standardPrice1);

        PricebookEntry standardPrice2 = new PricebookEntry(
                Pricebook2Id = pricebookId, Product2Id = prod.Id,
                UnitPrice = 0.0, IsActive = true,CurrencyIsoCode ='EUR');
         listStdPrice.add(standardPrice2);

           PricebookEntry standardPrice3 = new PricebookEntry(
                Pricebook2Id = pricebookId, Product2Id = prod.Id,
                UnitPrice = 0.0, IsActive = true,CurrencyIsoCode ='AUD');
        listStdPrice.add(standardPrice3);

         insert listStdPrice;

          // Create a custom price book
       Pricebook2 customPB = new Pricebook2(Name='Standard Price Book', isActive=true);
       insert customPB;

       //create custom Price book for each currency
       List<PriceBookEntry> listCustPrice = new List<PriceBookEntry>();
       PricebookEntry customPrice1 = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = customPB.Id, Product2Id = prod.Id,CurrencyIsoCode ='GBP',
                                                UnitPrice = 0.0, IsActive = true,useStandardPrice=false);
       listCustPrice.add(customPrice1);

       PricebookEntry customPrice2 = new PricebookEntry(
       Pricebook2Id = customPB.Id, Product2Id = prod1.Id,
       UnitPrice = 0.0, IsActive = true,useStandardPrice=false,CurrencyIsoCode ='USD');
       listCustPrice.add(customPrice2); 

       PricebookEntry customPrice3 = new PricebookEntry(
       Pricebook2Id = customPB.Id, Product2Id = prod2.Id,
       UnitPrice = 0.0, IsActive = true,useStandardPrice=false,CurrencyIsoCode ='EUR');
       listCustPrice.add(customPrice3); 

        PricebookEntry customPrice4 = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = customPB.Id, Product2Id = prod3.Id,CurrencyIsoCode ='AUD',
                                                UnitPrice = 0.0, IsActive = true,useStandardPrice=false);
       listCustPrice.add(customPrice4);

       insert listCustPrice;
```